# How to await a Rust Future on a non-async function

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, rust-actix

Rust newbie here (<7 days into learning), the second hurdle I am trying to overcome after ownership rule is async/await.

I am writing a test that calls an `async` function and I need to get the result from the `Future` without using the keyword `await`.

I have looked at `async_test`, however I can't use that because (as I understand) this requires `tokio` runtime and `#[tokio_main]` attribute in my `main` method - but I have my `main` already decorated with `#[actix_rt::main]`

This is my test

```rust
#[test]
pub fn test_get_item() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
    let c = SomeClient::new();
    let result = c.get_item(123456).await?; // <- this is not allowed

    assert_eq!("Hello", result.title);
    assert_eq!("https://example.com", result.url.as_str());

    Ok(())
}
```

Things I have tried and failed (mostly due to my lack of knowledge in Rust)

- Use `async_test` on an actix web project using [futures-await-test](https://github.com/ngg/futures-await-test/blob/master/futures-await-test/tests/test.rs) crate.
- Read this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7ku3f0/using_futures_in_non_async_code/) in reddit.
- Follow few examples from this [rust community thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-wait-an-async-in-non-async-function/28388/12)
- Tried to `poll()` the future but it didn't lead me anywhere.

I don't understand why this has to be so complicated, maybe there is a simple function (like `wait()` or `get_result()`) somewhere for `Future`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to clear my head for a bit and start again, just to find actix-web has a macro I can use that allows `async` tests.

```
#[actix_rt::test]
```

Macros are all magic to me at this point, I hope I;ll understand them soon.